# Execution time and resources after processes that has been running for so long

Tags: rhel, cpu, time, io

This might be a basic question, but I am getting hard time finding an answer to it.
I am using RHEL6. After running any process that takes significant cpu time, I get a line that tells  (I guess) the run-time and IO usage automatically. It reads like:

```
77410.101u 124.968s 1:42:43.49 657.9%    0+0k 0+1353384io 0pf+0w
```

I have the following questions:

1. How do I interpret each field in this message? I can guess some time,IO usage and may be CPU usage ... but I am not sure.
2. What actually prints this line? Is it the shell? Is it the terminal emulator? Is there a running daemon taking care of that? What is the name of this feature/service/whatever it is.
3. Is it possible to control this message? Like set the cpu usage threshold for printing it?
4. Can I add extra information to it? Like the absolute path of the process, peak memory usage, peak disk usage, etc ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Tip for debugging what's going on

I would suggest turning on the debug facility of your shell, assuming you're using Bash.

```
$ set -x
```

This output will show you what's happening behind the scenes when you run a command that produces this output.

#### The output

That output is from the time `/usr/bin/time` command being prefixed to every command you run. In order to get that output, I'm guessing you're using either C-shell (csh) or Turbo C-shell (tcsh).

#### Example

```
$ tcsh
$ time sleep 2
0.000u 0.000s 0:02.00 0.0%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

The reason I suspect this is a `tcsh` shell is that when I run the command `/usr/bin/time` in a Bash shell the output looks like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time sleep 2
0.00user 0.00system 0:02.02elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 580maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+180minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

The output can be controlled using the `-f` or `--format` switch, so the output you're seeing could be achieved in Bash as well, but would have to be done intentionally.

#### Meaning of output

If you run the command `/usr/bin/time` in verbose mode, (`-v`) you'll get all the details about each field like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v sleep 2
    Command being timed: "sleep 2"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:02.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 584
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 184
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 4
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

If you line up the original output:

```
77410.101u 124.968s 1:42:43.49 657.9%    0+0k 0+1353384io 0pf+0w
^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^    ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
     1        2         3       4         5        6        7
```

1. User time (seconds)
2. System time (seconds)
3. Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss)
4. Percent of CPU this job got
5. Average shared text size (kbytes) + Average unshared data size (kbytes)
6. Number of file system inputs by the process + Number of file system outputs by the process
7. Number  of major page faults that occurred while the process was running.  These are faults where the page has to be read in from disk + Number of times the process was swapped out of main memory

You can manually do the same format like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f '%Uu %Ss %E %P %X+%Dk %I+%Oio %Fpf+%Ww' sleep 2
0.00u 0.00s 0:02.00 0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

#### Customizing the output

Once you're able to determine where the call to `/usr/bin/time` is being made you can customize the output by taking a peak at the man page for `time`. There are lots of options that can be included in this output.

```
$ man time
```

*excerpt*

```
   Time
   %E     Elapsed real time (in [hours:]minutes:seconds).
   %e     (Not in tcsh.) Elapsed real time (in seconds).
   %S     Total number of CPU-seconds that the process spent in kernel mode.
   %U     Total number of CPU-seconds that the process spent in user mode.
   %P     Percentage of the CPU that this job got, computed as (%U + %S) / %E.

   Memory
   %M     Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kbytes.
   %t     (Not in tcsh.) Average resident set size of the process, in Kbytes.
   %K     Average total (data+stack+text) memory use of the process, in Kbytes.
   %D     Average size of the process's unshared data area, in Kbytes.
   %p     (Not in tcsh.) Average size of the process's unshared stack space, in Kbytes.
   %X     Average size of the process's shared text space, in Kbytes.
   %Z     (Not in tcsh.) System's page size, in bytes.  This is a per-system constant, but varies between systems.
   %F     Number  of major page faults that occurred while the process was running.  These are faults where the page has to be read
          in from disk.
   %R     Number of minor, or recoverable, page faults.  These are faults for pages that are not valid but which have not yet  been
          claimed by other virtual pages.  Thus the data in the page is still valid but the system tables must be updated.
   %W     Number of times the process was swapped out of main memory.
   %c     Number of times the process was context-switched involuntarily (because the time slice expired).
   %w     Number of waits: times that the program was context-switched voluntarily, for instance while waiting for an I/O operation
          to complete.

   I/O
   %I     Number of file system inputs by the process.
   %O     Number of file system outputs by the process.
   %r     Number of socket messages received by the process.
   %s     Number of socket messages sent by the process.
   %k     Number of signals delivered to the process.
   %C     (Not in tcsh.) Name and command-line arguments of the command being timed.
   %x     (Not in tcsh.) Exit status of the command.
```

See the man page for more details.

#### EDIT #1: Your issue

Turns out your question about the output being shown automatically is being caused by the setting of this environment variable in csh/tcsh.

*from the tcsh man page*

> ```
>    The time shell variable can be set to execute the time builtin command 
>      after the completion of any process that takes more  than a given number 
>      of CPU seconds.
> ```

#### Example

Set the time to 5 seconds.

```
$ set time=5
```

Confirm:

```
$ set|grep time
time    5
```

Test it out:

```
$ bash -c "while [ 1 ];do echo hi; done"
hi
hi
...
...waited ~5 seconds, then Ctrl-C to stop it

5.650u 1.471s 0:09.68 73.5% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

The output will only show up if the task you're running consumes more than the number of seconds of the CPU time set by the variable `$time`.

#### References

- [time man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)

Comment: Just for completeness: `time` is a builtin in bash as well, and its output differs from `/usr/bin/time` (real, user,sys over three lines).

Comment: @Bichoy - take a look at the update. Figured out what was printing your time outout.

Comment: Thanks @slm for thorough explanation and the edit.
Indeed this perfectly answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Bichoy - you're quite welcome. Thanks for the Q. I didn't know any of this before so your Q actually taught me something new too 8-).